# Single boot Ubuntu - need help with partitioning hard disk

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have an Acer laptop (E1-571) that came pre-installed with Windows 8. I then installed Ubuntu 14.04 to double boot alongside Win 8. Now, I want to get rid of my Windows installation and single boot Ubuntu 14.04.

I am stuck when it comes to partitioning my 500 GB hard disk. I made a swap partition of 4 GB, another 100 GB partition for /home and 25 GB for /.
This rendered the remaining 368 GB useless - I cant save files to it and it's completely empty.

Suppose I have to start the partitioning from scratch, how do I do it? Can someone guide me right from setting partitions as logical/primary/extended to fixing mount points and boot? I know that I have to boot from the Live USB and use GParted. I've done this once before so I don't know why this is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only Ubuntu and no Windows then you can let the partitioner do its job.

If you really want to partition manually then this is the generally accepted norm

- Set an equal amount of space for your swap partition as your ram. Set the mount point as `swap`
- set around 1GB for the `/boot` partition. Mount point is `/boot`
- set the rest for `/`

This config works for most cases.

Comment: I prefer no /boot and large /home or what I use which is a large data partition. But each user has his own requirements. I multi-boot Ubuntu versions just to see what next is like while using LTS as main working system. So then my data partition works well. May not be so good for others. http://askubuntu.com/questions/353683/uefi-partitioning-for-dummies and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: What do you mean by "let the partitioner do its job"? I get three options when I boot using Live USB - one of those is LVM and one is "something else" which lets me manually partition. What should I select to let the partitioner do its job?

Comment: after booting into live-usb you probably try to install ubuntu. In that process you get to the stage where you need to partition the hdd or at least choose your preferences. AFAIK the `LVM` and `Full disk encryption` are both checkboxes (something that you can tick) while the option `something else` is a radiobutton.  There should be another option that says something like "delete hard disk and install" or " install along another Os(if you are dual booting ofcourse)". This option should also be a radio button. Choose that.