# Dual boot with External Hard disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, external-hdd, windows-10

I have windows 10 on my lap and i don't want to install Ubuntu in here.
I have a external hard disk and i want to install Ubuntu in this.
How to achieve dual boot with both windows on system and Ubuntu on external hard disk?

I need following criteria to be satisfied :

- If i don't plug my external hard disk then the system should boot into windows 10.
- If i plug in external hard disk then i should have option to select windows 10 or Ubuntu.

Comment: Newer UEFI system or older BIOS upgraded install? Either way better to partition external as gpt, include ESP - efi system partition if UEFI or if chance drive may be later used with newer system, and bios_grub partition if BIOS. http://askubuntu.com/questions/353683/uefi-partitioning-for-dummies and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi

Comment: Just did a check . i am using UEFI.

Comment: Will you only be booting external from this computer? Grub only installs its boot files to the ESP on drive seen as sda, typically your internal drive. And then you can set boot order in UEFI to boot Ubuntu first and if not seen, boot Windows. But if you want to use external in UEFI mode with any other computer you have to copy /EFI/ubuntu to /EFI/ubuntu in ESP on external drive and then copy again to /EFI/Boot and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi. All external drives can directly boot with bootx64.efi. I would suggest copying the files even if only using the one system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by configuring the boot order in your BIOS settings.
You should set as primary boot device the external hard drive and as the second you should set the internal hard drive. That means that when an external hard drive(Ubuntu) is connected the system will boot of it and if not, the system will boot from the internal drive(WIndows 10)