# New build want to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu Dual boot on M.2 drive with Sata HDD for storage

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, partitioning, m2

The post from Oldfred seems to over the procedure but it's a little too concise for me and he uses a lot of technical language which makes it hard for me to follow.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2381504

So I just want to make sure that I understand the full procedure. Will need to be handheld!

The system is newly built with, no software is currently installed. The system has an asus Z370 motherboard which is UEFI.

1.) I first install windows to the M.2 drive using this guide using the instruction headed (To wipe and convert the drive by using Windows Setup)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style

2.) How do I ensure that this drive is sda?

3.) Next step fro Oldfred is to:  partition new SSD with gpt and include an ESP, whether That ESP is currently used or not.

I think this step is covered in more detail here correct?
[UEFI Partitioning for Dummies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353683/uefi-partitioning-for-dummies)

4.) Ubuntu now only needs / (root) and ESP if UEFI.
Install of 17.04 or later now use swap file not a swap partition.

What does he mean Ubuntu now only needs / (root)?
What does he mean by use a swap file not a swap partition?

5.) Do I have to partition (or do anything else) to the data drive as well?

The data drive is simply where I will hold the data, for my windows and ubuntu programs I just wondered if the data drive has to be partitioned as well because it will be used by different OS?

Thanks

Baz

Comment: Maybe the detailed instructions in this link will be helpful for you: [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Comment: Sorry if I have the wrong end of the stick but the M.2 drive is an internal drive. It will also be the boot drive?

Comment: It is best to boot from a USB pendrive and install the operating system(s) from that drive into the internal drive (the M2 drive). I guess you want to start by installing Windows, and after that install Ubuntu alongside Windows into the same drive or another drive, if you have more than one drive.

Comment: I have an M.2 drive that is seen as SATA or sda1. But newer M.2 NVMe drives have come down in price and are a lot faster, so you may have one of those. Best to understand UEFI. Both Windows & Ubuntu install in UEFI or BIOS boot mode depending on how you boot install media. So only boot in UEFI mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Also partitioning: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  See also sudodus' answer.

Comment: It's a simple process with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 using EFI boot. 1) Do a clean install of windows to the empty drive. 2) Shring the windows drive to free up some space. 3) Install Ubuntu to the freespace, setting it the root and direct the installer to install grub in that same root partition. Post installtion, boot selection fron bios, shift-restart from windows or efibootmgr are 3 options to allow you to select thich OS you wish to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General tip

Maybe the detailed instructions in this link will be helpful for you: [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

### Detailed answer

> Q.) How do I ensure that this drive is sda?

A.) When booted into the Ubuntu live drive, run the following commands to identify the drives and partitions,

```
df -h
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
sudo parted -ls
```

> Q.) Next step fro Oldfred is to:  partition new SSD with gpt and include an ESP, whether That ESP is currently used or not.
>
> I think this step is covered in more detail here correct?
>   [UEFI Partitioning for Dummies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353683/uefi-partitioning-for-dummies)

A.) Yes, I think so. You can also see this link:

[help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

> Q.) Ubuntu now only needs / (root) and ESP if UEFI. Install of 17.04 or later now use swap file not a swap partition.
>
> What does he mean Ubuntu now only needs / (root)?
>   What does he mean by use a swap file not a swap partition?

A.) You need no swap partition, when you use a swap file (which is automatically selected in most cases in the new versions of Ubuntu). It means that you need only the EFI system partition and the root partition.

> Q.) Do I have to partition (or do anything else) to the data drive as well?

A.) You can select an automatic partitioning method or 'Something else' alias manual partitioning. It is easiest to select the automatic partitioning 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu'.

**Edit:** But I am not sure what you mean by 'data drive'. A data drive is more or less independent of the operating system, as long as the file systems on the data drive are compatible and can be accessed (read/write).

Please explain in a comment, if you think I misunderstood the question.